# Reporting Services - Inverse Logarithmic scale for gauge

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We are using SSRS 2008 R2 Enterprise and would like to create a gauge with a scale between 0 and 100% with the halfway mark at 90% with a increasing interval from there.  This is to deal with normally high targets in the 98, 99, or even 99.85% range.

Does anyone know if it is possible to do this with the out of the box SSRS 2008R2 gauges?

Thanks in advance,
Dan